# Map json string value to enum type value

Tags: spring-boot

I am working in a SpringBoot project.

In my model class I have a enum type property:

```
public class Car {
   CarType type;
   ...
}
```

The enum CarType:

```
public enum CarType {
  SEDAN, HATCHBACK, SUV
}
```

In my DTO layer, the payload of request should tell the car type, normally it uses `String` type to indicate car type:

```
public class RequestPayload {
   String carType;
   ...
}
```

But if I define it as enum type:

```
public class RequestPayload {
       CarType carType;
       ...
}
```

I wonder is there a way to directly map the value from json to enum type value?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define carType as an `enum` in your DTO Layer.

```
public class RequestPayload {
       CarType carType;
       ...
}
```

It will Automatically Maps `Json` value to `enum` and in case value doesn't match `enum` values then will throw an `Exception`.

Comment: Do you mean springboot will automatically maps json to enum? Or who will do so exactly? Do I need to have dependency of some 3rd party library to do so?

Comment: No, you don't need any Third party Library to do the same. Springboot will Automatically maps it.